# MySQL assigning primary key for id is not working while creating table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i am trying to create table like this but it is not working:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
);
```

Where as when i create like this it is working fine

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I'm confused what is wrong in my first query.?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363092/what-is-wrong-with-this-mysql-query

Comment: In what way is it "not working"?  Is there an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the primary key what is causing your trouble the syntax is correct. 
The last line has a syntax error, the comma on the last line is wrong.

```
  CREATE TABLE `users` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      `name` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
      `email` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
    )
```

should be

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(70) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: oops, thnx. i didn't catch that typo.